# Draw string on button with a handler instead of renderer

Tags: c#, android, maui

We're using currently a custom `ButtonRenderer` to draw a string additionally to the buttons text.

```
public class HotkeyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    public HotkeyButtonRenderer(Context ctx) : base(ctx)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        SetWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (Element is not null && (
            e.PropertyName == HotkeyButton.HotkeyTextProperty.PropertyName ||
            e.PropertyName == HotkeyButton.BorderColorProperty.PropertyName))
        {
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);
        if (Element is HotkeyButton element && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.HotkeyText))
        {
            string textToDraw = $"({element.HotkeyText})";
            float textSize = Control.TextSize / 1.5f;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Rect textBounds = new Rect();
            paint.TextSize = textSize;
            paint.GetTextBounds(textToDraw,0,textToDraw.Length, textBounds);
            int textHeight = textBounds.Height();
            float x = 5;
            float y = Height- textHeight / 2;

            canvas.DrawText(textToDraw,
                x,
                y,
                new TextPaint
                {
                    Color = element.BorderColor.ToAndroid(),
                    TextSize = textSize
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

As the renderers are deprecated i want to change the implementation to the new `Handler` concept. How can i achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an almost working example of a `ButtonHandler` that sets the `Background` that takes a `Drawable`. For Android.

**The HotkeyButton**

```cs
public class HotkeyButton : Button
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HotkeyTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(HotkeyText), typeof(string), typeof(HotkeyButton), default(string));

    public string HotkeyText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(HotkeyTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(HotkeyTextProperty, value);
    }

    public new static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(HotkeyButton), default(Color));

    public new Color BorderColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**The Handler**

```cs
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Util;
using Google.Android.Material.Button;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
using APaint = Android.Graphics.Paint;
using Color = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color;

public class HotkeyButtonHandler : ButtonHandler
{
    public static readonly IPropertyMapper<IButton, ButtonHandler> HotkeyButtonMapper =
        new PropertyMapper<IButton, ButtonHandler>(Mapper)
        {
            [nameof(HotkeyButton.HotkeyText)] = MapHotkeyText,
        };

    public HotkeyButtonHandler() : base(HotkeyButtonMapper, CommandMapper)
    {
    }

    public HotkeyButtonHandler(IPropertyMapper mapper, CommandMapper commandMapper) : base(mapper ?? HotkeyButtonMapper, commandMapper)
    {
    }

    private static void MapHotkeyText(ButtonHandler handler, IButton button)
    {
        if (handler is HotkeyButtonHandler hotkeyButtonHandler)
            hotkeyButtonHandler.PlatformView.Background = new BackgroundDrawable(hotkeyButtonHandler);
    }

    protected override void ConnectHandler(MaterialButton platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
    }

    protected override void DisconnectHandler(MaterialButton platformView)
    {
        base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);
    }

    public override void UpdateValue(string property)
    {
        base.UpdateValue(property);

        if (property == HotkeyButton.HotkeyTextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            this.PlatformView.Background = new BackgroundDrawable(this);
        }
    }

    internal class BackgroundDrawable : Drawable
    {
        private readonly HotkeyButtonHandler hotkeyButtonHandler;

        public BackgroundDrawable(HotkeyButtonHandler hotkeyButtonHandler)
        {
            this.hotkeyButtonHandler = hotkeyButtonHandler;
        }

        public override int Opacity => 1;

        public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            if (hotkeyButtonHandler.VirtualView is HotkeyButton element && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.HotkeyText))
            {
                string textToDraw = $"({element.HotkeyText})";
                float textSize = (float)hotkeyButtonHandler.PlatformView.TextSize / 1.5f;

                var paint = new APaint()
                {
                    TextSize = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)textSize, hotkeyButtonHandler.PlatformView.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics),
                    Color = element.BorderColor.ToPlatform(),
                    TextAlign = APaint.Align.Left,
                    AntiAlias = true
                };
                paint.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Fill);

                // Some variable for testing positioning of the Text
                var width = (int)(paint.MeasureText(element.HotkeyText) + .5f);
                var baseline = (int)(-paint.Ascent() + .5f);
                var height = (int)(baseline + paint.Descent() + .5f);

                float xPos = canvas.Width / 2;
                float yPos = (int)((canvas.Height / 2) - ((paint.Descent() + paint.Ascent()) / 2));

                canvas.DrawText(textToDraw, xPos, yPos, paint);
            }
        }

        public override void SetAlpha(int alpha)
        {
            return;
        }

        public override void SetColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Add the Handler to the builder in `MauiProgram.cs`

```cs
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
               fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
               fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");

             })
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
               handlers.AddHandler<HotkeyButton, HotkeyButtonHandler>();
            })
```

And the implementation

```xml
<local:HotkeyButton
                BorderColor="Red"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                HotkeyText="M"
                Text="Test"
                TextColor="Red"
                WidthRequest="200" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a Custom Handler:

```
    public class HotkeyButtonHandler : AbstractViewHandler<HotkeyButton, Android.Widget.Button>
{
    protected override Android.Widget.Button CreateNativeView()
    {
        return new Android.Widget.Button(Context);
    }

    protected override void ConnectHandler(Android.Widget.Button nativeView)
    {
        // Handle property changes and updates to the native view here.
    }

    protected override void DisconnectHandler(Android.Widget.Button nativeView)
    {
        // Clean up and disconnect from the native view here.
    }
}
```

Create a Custom HotkeyButton:

```
public class HotkeyButton : View
{
    // Define properties and methods specific to your HotkeyButton.
}
```

Platform-Specific Initialization:

```
[assembly: ExportViewHandler(typeof(HotkeyButton), typeof(HotkeyButtonHandler))]
namespace YourNamespace.Droid
{
    // No need to implement anything here, the ExportViewHandler attribute is sufficient.
}
```

By following these steps, you'll be migrating from the deprecated renderer concept to the new handler concept for custom rendering in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: The Draw method does not exist in a handler.

Comment: corrected the code and removed draw method

Comment: So how will be the hotkey text drawn now?